# How to access service parameter from WSO2 ESB sequence

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I configured Proxy Service parameter according to the documentation:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CQProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
       ...
   </target>
   <parameter name="TestParam">ParamValue1</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Now I need to access it from within the sequence. Is there any way to do it?

I tried accessing it using script mediator:

```
 <script language="js">mc.setProperty("TestParamProp", mc.getParameter("TestParam"))</script>
```

but it throws "Cannot find function getParameter." error.

Please advice.

Comment: Did you check mc.getParameter("$ctx:TestParam")?

Comment: It does not work neither. The problem is that mc.getParameter() function is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

use the following to access the ESB params from the script mediator

```
<script language="js"> var test_param = mc.getProperty('TestParam') </script>
```

Use the following to retrieve the params within the script mediator back to the ESB

```
mc.setProperty("newParam",test_param)
```

Comment: This clause will access Properties not Parameters

Comment: This is not possible please refer to the following URL[1]. You can achieve this by setting the parameter and the property at the same time and pass the property value to the script mediator. [1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562087/how-to-get-the-property-transport-vfs-fileuri-in-sequence-wso2

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is no clear way to access Proxy Service parameter from within a sequence. Thanks!

Comment: You can set it as a property and access

Answer (score 0):

Give the input in json format and try the code given below,

```
<property name="TestParam" expression="json-eval($.TestParam)"></property>
<script language="js">
mc.setProperty("TestParamProp", mc.getProperty("TestParam"));
</script>
```